# Error Registering Hibernate TypeDef

Tags: hibernate

I have a system where some long-departed coder decided that when a user is locked out, the account_locked value should be "P" instead of "Y". "N" is still equivalent to a false value. And of course, since it's a production system, I can't modify it to use a standard "Y".

So, I borrowed the code from the standard Hibernate YesNoType and modified it as follows:

```
public class PasswordLockType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Boolean>
implements PrimitiveType<Boolean>, DiscriminatorType<Boolean> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final PasswordLockType INSTANCE = new PasswordLockType();

    public PasswordLockType() {
        super( CharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, BooleanTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE );
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "passwordLock";
    }

    public Class getPrimitiveClass() {
        return boolean.class;
    }

    public Boolean stringToObject(String xml) throws Exception {
        return fromString( xml );
    }

    public Serializable getDefaultValue() {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "UnnecessaryUnboxing" })
    public String objectToSQLString(Boolean value, Dialect dialect) throws Exception {
        return StringType.INSTANCE.objectToSQLString( value.booleanValue() ? "P" : "N", dialect );
    }

}
```

Then I modified the ApplicationUser class as follows:

```
@Entity
@TypeDefs(
        @TypeDef(name="passwordLock", typeClass=PasswordLockType.class)
)
public class ApplicationUser implements UserDetails, Comparable<ApplicationUser>, Serializable {

    // other fields

    private Boolean accountLocked;

    @Column(name = "LOCK_CD")
    @Type(type="passwordLock")
    public Boolean getAccountLocked() {
        return accountLocked;
    }
```

Unfortunately, the typedef seems to be ignored. (Actually, I'm still seeing "Y" getting written to the database, even though we removed the Hibernate YesNoType).

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Just found this thread while doing something similar. In my scenario I also changed the constructor passing some arguments to theBooleanTypeDescriptor:

```
private static final char CHARACTER_VALUE_TRUE = 'J';
private static final char CHARACTER_VALUE_FALSE = 'N';

public JaNeinType() {
    super(CharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, new BooleanTypeDescriptor(CHARACTER_VALUE_TRUE, CHARACTER_VALUE_FALSE));
}
```